# RefineryCMS consuming too many resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I've developed a RefineryCMS-based app, and I'm hosting it at Site5, with the plan [HOSTPRO + TURBO](http://www.site5.com/hosting/web/).

A couple of weeks ago I've got the folder disabled because the support people told me it was consuming too many computer resources. Below is what they told me:

> After some recent problems with the
>   server
>   riverthames.accountservergroup.com we
>   found that your site is causing those
>   problems due to your site's resource
>   usage. Your site is using too many
>   system resources (CPU and Memory) for
>   shared hosting. With shared hosting
>   you are sharing the hardware resources
>   with other people and unfortunately
>   your site is using more than it's fair
>   share. Unfortunately this means that
>   your site is going to need dedicated
>   hardware resources.
>
> Here is a summary of your CPU and
>   memory usage on your account over the
>   past 24 hours:
>
> CPU: 11.17 % MEM: 2.18 %
>
> We believe the processes shown below
>   are responsible for this level of
>   resource usage, please keep in mind if
>   you run a dynamic site off WordPress
>   or another script it might just show
>   index.php which is the primary file
>   that runs the entire site:
>
> --------------- Top Process %CPU 99.3 Rack: /home/usr/app/current Top
>   Process %CPU 71.7 Rack:
>   /home/usr/app/current  Top Process
>
> ### %CPU 71.5 Rack: /home/usr/app/current

Any ideas about what could be causing it?

Comment: How much traffic are you getting?

Comment: It's not a traffic issue I guess, because it was happening even before making it public.

Comment: There was an issue with performance in a recent release. This was fixed soon after. Is your code base up-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

I had to move my Rails apps (some Refinery) away from site5 because of the same problems. They simply aren't setup to run Rails apps well imho. Slow Ruby 1.8.7, no ability to tweak passenger (main problem was the amount of app instances spinning up was eating up memory fast).

I'd also recommend setting up New Relic to get some more details on where the memory is going.